# Indexing one-dimensional numpy.array as matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to index a *numpy.array* with varying dimensions during runtime. To retrieve e.g. the first row of a n*m array `a`, you can simply do

```
a[0,:]
```

However, in case a happens to be a *1xn* vector, this code above returns an index error:

> IndexError: too many indices

As the code needs to be executed as efficiently as possible I don't want to introduce an `if` statement. Does anybody have a convenient solution that ideally doesn't involve changing any data structure types?

Comment: You only have 1- and 2D arrays?

Comment: Would simply reshaping the array to be a 2d 1xn array instead of a 1d n-length array count as "changing the data structure type"?

Comment: All these are 2D arrays (mxn) theoretically, some just happend to be 1xn arrays, e.g. m=1. In fact they represent conditional probability tables and the case m=1 corresponds to a variable that doesn't have any dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `a[0]` instead of `a[0,:]`.  It will return the first line for a matrix and the first entry for a vector.  Is this what you are looking for?

If you want to get the whole vector in the one-dimensional case instead, you can use `numpy.atleast_2d(a)[0]`.  It won't copy your vector -- it will just access it as a two-dimensional 1 x n-array.

Comment: I didn't know about atleast_2d; handy. +1

Comment: I can second that, numpy.atleast_2d is very helpful and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From the [*'array' or 'matrix'? Which should I use?*](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935) section of the [Numpy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) wiki page:

> For array, the vector shapes 1xN, Nx1, and N are all different things. Operations like A[:,1] return a rank-1 array of shape N, not a rank-2 of shape Nx1. Transpose on a rank-1 array does nothing.

Here's an example showing that they are not the same:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a1
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a2 = np.array([[1,2,3]])    // Notice the two sets of brackets
>>> a2
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a3 = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
>>> a3
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

So, are you sure that all of your arrays are 2d arrays, or are some of them 1d arrays?

If you want to use your command of `array[0,:]`, I would recommend actually using 1xN 2d arrays instead of 1d arrays. Here's an example:

```
>>> a2 = np.array([[1,2,3]])    // Notice the two sets of brackets
>>> a2
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a2[0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> b2
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b2[0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
```